# Como desativar o Pop-UP do Google Chrome para salvar senhas?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Como seria um método para desativar o *`Pop-Up:`*

> Deseja que o Google Chrome atualize sua senha para este site?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fique a vontade para escolher a linguagem, mas a resposta com `JavaScript` será a resposta aceita.

***`Nota:`*** [`AutoComplete='Off'`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) indica ao navegador que não é necessário exibir opções com base em valores anteriores, então não é isso que desejo.

Comment: Relacionado em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177225/how-do-i-disable-the-save-password-bubble-in-chrome-using-javascript

Comment: Quem negativou poderia explicar o porque? Assim eu poderia melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters através do link consegui chegar a resposta! Vlw :)

Comment: Agora são dois negativos. Parece que tem uma galerinha que não gostou da pergunta, mas não pode explicar bem o que houve.

Comment: Parece que sim, vai entender =D;

Comment: já entendi. Deve ser porque você mesmo respondeu, porém a galera não sabe que o sistema do site incentiva isso :p

Comment: Posso perguntar por quê você deseja fazer isso? Não consigo visualizar um ambiente em que a filosofia do navegador de armazenar senhas possa entrar em conflito com a aplicação.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pode sim. Estou criando criando um `Redefinir Senha` e sempre que o formulário é submetido o `Crome` está fazendo este tipo de pergunta.

Comment: @Marconi mas não é interessante que ele faça isso para não manter a senha antiga armazenada ao invés da nova?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss no meu caso não, até porque este usuário que está no print não é o que estou alterando a senha.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso gerou uma certa confusão no tester aqui, e ela achou melhor retirar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227071/como-desativar-o-pop-up-do-google-chrome-para-salvar-senhas/227080?noredirect=1#comment465034_227071) do @Wallace Maxters, descobri que em nenhum local diz exatamente como desativar este `Pop-UP`(*por maneiras corretas*), mas existem meios de ***burlar*** isto.

## Porque isso acontece?

Sempre que um formulário com `<input  type="password">` é enviado o `Chrome` irá fazer a pergunta do `Pop-UP`.

## E qual a solução para isso?

Adicione 2 campos falsos ao lado do seu campo de senha.

```
<input type="password" class="stealthy" tabindex="-1">
<input type="password" " id="user_password" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" class="stealthy" tabindex="-1">
```

E use o seguinte `CSS`

```
.stealthy {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 1px;
  max-width: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

O motivo da classe `CSS` é torna os campos  invisíveis e desclassificados.

Comment: Isso não faz com que os caracteres do campo fiquem visíveis?

Comment: @Renan editada, essa resposta resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado por mencionar aqui ;)

Comment: Essa resposta ainda não é definitiva. Os desenvolvedores dos principais [tomaram a decisão de forçar o armazenamento local de senhas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) e técnicas como essa irão eventualmente parar de funcionar em alguma atualização futura. A solução que você colocou aqui não é a primeira e nem será a última forma de se evitar que o Chrome salve senhas, é apenas a forma que funciona hoje.

Answer (score 1):

Não podemos desabilitar essa função diretamente via Javascript, pois isto é uma configuaração do próprio navegador.
Mas podemos utilizar um código para "burlar" isto ...

Você pode tentar copiar a senha para um campo 'hidden' e remover do input 'original', antes de enviar o 'submit';
Exemplo :

```
function executeAdjustment(){       
    $("#vPassword").val($("#txtPassword").val());
    $(":password").remove();        
    var myForm = document.getElementById("createServerForm");
    myForm.action = "executeCreditAdjustment.do";
    myForm.submit();
}
```

Ref. [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177225/how-do-i-disable-the-save-password-bubble-in-chrome-using-javascript)