# Não deixar navegador salvar a senha

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estou precisando fazer com que o navegador não salve a senha do usuário, já tentei autocomplete="off", autocomplete="new-password", já coloquei no form da pagina autocomplete="off", porém mesmo assim o navegador pede para salvar a senha, como posso fazer para não deixar salvar? Ou o campo nem perguntar ?

```html
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtsenha" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" autocomplete="new-password" type="password" placeholder="Senha"></asp:TextBox>
```

Tentei incluir essa linha antes, para enganar o navegador:

```html
 <input style="display: none" />
```

Tentei também colocar com o mesmo name para enganar o navegador, e nenhuma forma funcionou, alguém tem algum exemplo eficaz pra me ajudar?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se funciona, mas você já tentou setar os atributos `TextMode="Password"`, `EnableViewState="false"`  e `AutoComplete="off"` no campo ASP?

Comment: Não tentei, porém fiz o teste agora, e não funcionou também.

Comment: Seria isso? [Como desativar o Pop-UP do Google Chrome para salvar senhas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227071/como-desativar-o-pop-up-do-google-chrome-para-salvar-senhas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não posso afirmar, mas creio que na maioria dos navegadores se colocar na tag `<form>` deve funcionar:

```
<form action="baz.aspx" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Claro que independente disto, isto é algo de controle do usuário, é um facilitador, penso eu que deve ser **escolha do usuário** se ele quer ou não salvar.

Claro que existem soluções alternativas que talvez resolvam o problema, como usar um `form` falso combinado com Ajax, ou seja, provavelmente nem usaria `asp:TextBox runat=server` por exemplo (não deve ficar dentro de `form`):

```
<div id="meu-form" data-url="foo.aspx" data-location="/dashboard/">
    <input name="login" autocomplete="off">
    <input name="pass" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="logar">Logar</button>
</div>
```

E no Ajax ficaria assim:

```
var form = document.getElementById('meu-form'),
    requesting = false;

actLogon.onclick = function() {
    if (requesting) return;

    //Bloqueia as requisições enquanto estiver logando
    requesting = true;

    var action = form.dataset.url;
    var loc = form.dataset.location;

    var actLogon = form.querySelector('button.logar');
    var login = form.querySelector('login');
    var pass = form.querySelector('pass');

    //Variaveis que vão para o servidor
    var variaveis = [
         "login=" + encodeURIcomponent(login),
         "pass=" + encodeURIcomponent(pass)
    ].join("&");

    //Ajax
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest;

    oReq.open("POST", action, true);

    //Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (oReq.status === 200) {
                if (oReq.responseText === "sucesso") {
                    window.location.replace(loc);
                } else {
                    alert("Erro: " + oReq.responseText);
                }
            } else {
                alert("Erro: " + oReq.status);
            }

            actLogon = false;
        }
    };

    //Envia a requisição, mas a resposta fica sendo aguardada em Background
    oReq.send(variaveis);
};
```

Explicando o código:

- O `<div id="meu-form" data-url="foo.aspx" data-location="/dashboard/">` vai ficar no lugar do form
- O `data-url="foo.aspx"` deve conter o valor da URL que será usada **somente para o ajax**
- O `data-location="/dashboard/"` deve conter a URL de destino, ou seja a tela depois que o usuário estiver logado
- As `variaveis` devem conter as chaves e valores que vai pegar na pagina do Ajax (`foo.aspx` é somente um exemplo)

  ```
  var variaveis = [
       "login=" + encodeURIcomponent(login),
       "pass=" + encodeURIcomponent(pass)
  ].join("&");
  ```
- O teu aspx deve retornar somente o texto `sucesso` na resposta para o Ajax, se o login tiver sido correto:

  ```
  if (oReq.responseText === "sucesso") {
      window.location.replace(loc);
  } else {
      alert("Erro: " + oReq.responseText);
  }
  ```

  Caso contrário irá exibir o `alert` com uma mensagem de erro, que você pode customizar.

No `foo.aspx` (independente do nome que dê), deve ficar algo como:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

var login = context.Request.Form["login"];
var pass = context.Request.Form["pass"];

//Faz o login aqui

if (/*Se o login estiver correto*/) {
    context.Response.Write("sucesso");
} else {
    context.Response.Write("Erro");
}

context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Fiz isso na minha página, porém não funcionou, continua dando a opção, por questão de segurança, foi decidido pela equipe, para não deixar o usuário salvar a senha.

Comment: @marianac_costa veja se consegue entender o exemplo em Ajax que fiz

Comment: @marianac_costa editei a resposta para adicionar mais algumas explicações

Answer (score 0):

Vendo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111774/6200920) do SO

Faltou setar o `type="password"` no `input hidden'`. Também é necessário que esse `input` venha antes do `input` que realmente será usado.

```
<form>
    <div style="display: none">
         <input  type="password" />
    </div>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsenha" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" autocomplete="new-password" type="password" placeholder="Senha"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

Comment: Já tentei desta forma, porém também não funcionou.

Comment: Já tentou deixando em uma `div hidden`? editei a resposta

Comment: Também não funcionou, fiz o teste colocando uma antes, e uma depois do txtsenha, porém também não resolveu.